# Protocol buffer serialization: Could not insert serialized repeated field into SQL server

Tags: c++, sql-server, serialization, char, protocol-buffers

I am using Google protocol buffer for serialization. Here is the .proto file:

```
message Word
{
message Record
{
     optional uint64 id = 1; 
     optional string word = 2;
     optional double value = 3;
}
message RecordSeq
{
    repeated Record RecSeq = 1;
}
}
```

I serialized a RecordSeq message to string using SerializeAsString(). In my code, at some place, I did something like the following:

```
Word::RecordSeq recseq;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
Word::Record *rec = recseq.add_recseq();
rec->set_id(4);
rec->set_word("program");
rec->set_value(1.0);
}

std::string result = recseq.SerializeAsString();
```

Now I want to insert this serialized message into SQL server database. For this I want `const char*`. However, when I converted to char* through `result.c_str()`, the result got truncated. I printed out the result, and figured out there are white space in it.

My insert function is having both result and its length as its arguments.

```
Insert(result.c_str(), result.length());
```

I tried to use `result.data()` as well. It is also truncating the result. Is there any other way to do this ?

I tried to deserialize the message without converting it to `const char*`. It is deserializing it correctly.

```
Word::RecordSeq recseq;
recseq.ParseFromString(result);

for(int j=0;j<recseq.recseq_size();j++)
{
const Word::Record& rec = recseq.recseq(j);
std::cout<<rec.word()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<rec.id()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<rec.value()<<std::endl;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does SerializeToString use the binary format? Or the text format? I would have assumed binary, in which case any tools that look for nil bytes are going to break the data; nil bytes are common in protobuf binary data.

Comment: @MarcGravell: It is binary format. Then how can I insert the result into SQL server ?

Comment: by being very careful not to use any methods that check for nil bytes as a terminator. Alternatively, use the stream or void* methods.